# Passing data between dialog and activity

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am developing a small basic app.I have four buttons in my app.What I need is when the user presses the button,I want a dialog to be displayed full screen and particular set of `text views`.For example:
I have the following buttons like:
1)Heroes
2)Movies.  On pressing heroes button a list of heroes should appear similarly for movies.The only way I know is creating a new activity for every button press.Instead I want a single dialog to be displayed for all four buttons but the data displayed on the dialog should vary according to button.Is this possible? I know this question is lengthy and could be asked in a better way.Please give me any suggestions

Comment: If you're displaying the dialog full screen, Why do you want it to be a dialog?  Seems like your first thought of showing a new activity is the best.  Maybe you can explain why the dialog is critical in order to get better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Method which create Custom `Dialog` with required number of `TextView`s and pass your `String` values to the method

Refer this example

*dialog_layout*

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/declineButton"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Submit "
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textDialog"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageDialog"
    />
```

Place this `showDialog()` method in activity

```
        private void showDialog(){   
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomDialog.this);
            // Include dialog.xml file
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            // Set dialog title
            dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
            // Set Dialog fullscreen
             dialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
            text.setText("Custom dialog Android example.");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image0);

            dialog.show();

            Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
            // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Close dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

Refer complete example here http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88